# How to use ld to link compiled .o files

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have a simple program with 2 files:

test.c:

```
#include "head.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

func.c:

```
#include "head.h"

void print(void)
{
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

and the head file "head.h":

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print(void);
```

I would like to use ld to link the compiled .o files, so:

```
compile:
    gcc -c -m64 *.c
linkelf:
    ld -m elf_x86_64 -o a.out *.o -lc
```

However, the ld command report a warning of no _start, and the output file cannot run.

If I change the "main" function to "_start", it doesn't report but still cannot run.

I've searched across internet, and cannot find a way to use ld to link the file.

I also use -v to output gcc command, and using it as the option of ld, but reporting error of not finding temp files.

I only need to create a executable file and a dynamic library. Would there be an easy way of doing that?

Comment: *Would there be an easy way of doing that?* - the easy way is to let GCC do it for you: `gcc -o a.out *.o`. When calling `ld` to generate an ELF which uses the libc some additional library specific `.o` files are needed, it's not going to be very clean nor simple (and if those files are located somewhere else than where you expect, it also fails). Run `gcc -v -o a.out *.o` to see how GCC calls `ld`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I tried to use -v and using the output as argument of ld, it report errors of cannot locating some files under temp directory

Comment: Those are temporary files generated by GCC, you cannot use the command *as is*, you need to only keep what you need. It's not simple, as I said. See the answer I linked above.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I simply use -lc can compile, but cannot run........